# How to provide generated Routes using ROUTES InjectionToken in a module-less Angular App?

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I'm converting to Standalone Components and as they suggest to convert the routes to that:

```
// In the main application:
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  {path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/routes')},
  // ...
];

// In admin/routes.ts:
export default [
  {path: 'home', component: AdminHomeComponent},
  {path: 'users', component: AdminUsersComponent},
  // ...
] as Route[];
```

But in my current RoutingModule i provide the Routes dynamically using the `ROUTES InjectionToken`.

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: (gfConfigService: GfConfigService): Routes => gfConfigService.createRoutes(),
      deps: [GfConfigService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

Context: So the routes are not really dynamically, but the creation of the Routes depends on some data which is stored in the `GfConfigService`.

Any idea's how to get rid of this RoutingModule, while still providing the `automatic generated routes` and still load them `lazy` when the router hit's for example `/admin`?

Answer (score 1):

this is my working example

```
export function routeHandler(auth: Auth) {

  const user = auth.currentUser;
  let routes: Routes = []
  if (!auth.currentUser) {
    routes = [{
      path: '',
      loadComponent: () => import('./mt-auth/mt-auth.component').then(x => x.MtAuthComponent)
    }]
  }
  
  routes.push({ path: '**', redirectTo: '' })
  return routes;
  
}
```

```
....
provideRouter([]),
{ provide: ROUTES, useFactory: routeHandler, deps: [Auth], multi: true },
....
```